# How to get value from an Array() at index in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
    let urlPath: String = "http://binaenaleyh.net/dusor/"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var imgData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

    let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(imgData, options: nil, error: &error) as NSDictionary

    println(jsonDict["dersler"])
```

It returns the whole JSON value, but I need the value at a specific index only.

Comment: Dude, don't edit my answer just to ask a question. Leave a comment if you want to ask something. That error you are getting, restart Xcode.

Comment: It's give you right answer. returns *Array of dictionary* and if you want the specific dictionary item then you have to follow @Fogmeister answer

Answer (score 3):

I take it `jsonDict` is either an `NSDictionary` or a `[NSObject:AnyObject]`? First off, you shouldn't be using `valueForKey()`. The appropriate method on `NSDictionary` is `objectForKey`. But even better, you can just subscript it.

Of course, the results of the subscript are a value typed as `AnyObject`, and you can't just subscript that. You need to cast it to the appropriate type. If you know the cast will succeed you can just use `as`, otherwise you'll need `as?`. Assuming the latter, this would look like

```
if let ary = jsonDict["dersler"] as? [Int] {
    let x: Int = ary[0]
    println(x)
}
```

Comment: the actual array has _dictionaries_, like `{"0": "2013-2014", "1": "BAHAR", "2": "2", "3": "CEE 102", "4": "Logic Circuits", "5": "3", "6": "6.00", "7": "YRD.DO\u00c7.DR.INDRIT MYDERRIZI", "8": "0", "9": "IA", "10": "TeacherHold", "11": "2", "12": ""}` instead of `Int` pure values. probably that is why the type-casting is not correct.

Answer (score -3):

Surely you can just do...

```
println(jsonDict["dersler"][0])
```

?

This has been asked many times too.

Comment: You can't use quotes inside an interpolated value. Luckily, you don't actually need the interpolation at all. `println(foo)` works just fine.

Comment: @KevinBallard thanks. Updated. Could you use single quotes? i.e. `jsonDict['dersler']`?